# Consuming web service and inserting CLOB using Node.js to Oracle Database table

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, api, webservice-client

i need to consume third party webservice using node js and write it on oracle table . basically i got the code for getting the data. Basically need to take that output and insert into a Oracle clob columns.Can someone guide me with examples.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Oracle introduced its JSON capability in 12c, and have added features ever since.

Answer (score 0):

Some resources:

- https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples has LOB examples, for example [lobinsert1.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/lobinsert1.js) and [lobinsert2.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/lobinsert2.js)
- There is plenty of documentation on using LOBs in node-oracledb in the node-oracledb manual, see [Working with CLOB, NCLOB and BLOB Data](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#lobhandling).

For example:

```
    // Insert a CLOB
    const str = fs.readFileSync(clobInFileName, 'utf8');
    result = await connection.execute(
      `INSERT INTO no_lobs (id, c) VALUES (:id, :c)`,
      { id: 1, c: str }
    );
    if (result.rowsAffected != 1)
      throw new Error('CLOB was not inserted');
    else
      console.log('CLOB inserted from ' + clobInFileName);
```

In your case you would read `str` from your web service instead of a disk
file.   Since I don't know what that web service is, I can't comment more.

Installation instructions for node-oracledb are [here](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html).

Comment: in case if i want to insert parsed json then what should i do. What is the syntax for that.

Comment: Start by updating your question and give details such as DB versions and the column datatypes.  Give some code to show what you mean 'parsed json' - is it a JS object or a String?

Comment: Thanks , i have posted a new case . Basically i need to understand how the insert works in case if the json is parsed when i say that mening writing directly to tables.