# Consume web service in Node.js and bulk insert to Oracle Database

Tags: sql, node.js, json, oracle, node-oracledb

I need to consume third party webservice using node js and write it to oracle table . Basically I got the code for getting the data. What is the command to insert bulk data into oracle from node json? I will be getting a huge file and I am parsing it. The code is as below.

Can someone help me with insert command here?

```
    const express = require("express");
    const oracledb = require("oracledb");
    const cors = require("cors");
    const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
    const request = require("request");
    let app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyparser.json());
    app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
    app.get("/demo",(req,res)=>{
            oracledb.getConnection({
                user:"INFO",
                password:"12345",
                connectString:"194.234.222.22:1521/TEST"
            },(err,connection)=>{
                if(err) throw err;
                else{
                    //make request call
                    try{
                        request.post({
                            url:     'https://qmilet.com/api/v1/partners/login',
                            body:    {"user":"_api","password":"_api"},
                            json: true
                        }, function(error, response, body){
                            //console.log(body);
                            token = body.access_token
                            console.log(token);
                            //make api request
                            //31ae0b786d4958c0a93a459f46a59d67b8a9cff8
                            try{
                                //replace thw dynamic token
                                //Syntax : ${token}
                                request.post({
                                    url : `https://qmilet.com/api/v1/orders/pull?access_token=${token}&date_from=2020-05-01&date_to=2021-05-30&include_synced=1`
                                },function(err,response,body){
                                    let obj = JSON.parse(body);
                                    res.send(obj.data);
                                    
                                    //how to read parsed data, and insert into oracle db
                                    
                                })
                            }catch(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });                
                    }catch(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }
            });    
    });
    
    
    app.listen(8080,()=>{
        console.log("server started");
    });
```

I am using 12.1.0.2 version of Oracle.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Oracle introduced its JSON capability in 12c, and have added features ever since.

Comment: You already asked this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327068/consuming-web-service-and-inserting-clob-using-node-js-to-oracle-database-table and I gave some (useful) resources.  But I don't see any attempt to apply what those references show.  Do you have a specific question about node-oracledb?  I'd be happy to help, but you haven't given enough info about the problem, or tried to simplify the example to the critical minimum.

Comment: i am using 12.1.0.2 version of Oracle. Yes this question is slightly different as i have tried to call this url. i am missing out on insert statement.

Comment: JSON is nested data. An Oracle table is tabular data. You need to have some kind of mapping between the two.

Comment: yes i am trying to find that mapping examples , can someone give me one real example.

Comment: You are the only one who knows what the JSON looks like, and what the target table looks like, so you are the only one who can do the mapping.

Comment: The other question you asked (which looks abandoned to me) had a link that eventually leads to this sample: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/example.js This sample has an example of an insert statement.

Comment: in git there is no straightforward example for reading and inserting into oracle

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. That sample code has a sample of inserting into Oracle. Start by using that sample code to extend your existing code to write... anything.... into Oracle. Then we can start on extracting data from JSON.

Comment: Hard luck , there are errors while inserting into it. it says oracledb.execute is not a function, is there a simple step by step method.